# Compile under Ubuntu with different header type

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, g++

I have 3 files namely "main.cpp", "testclass.cpp" and "testclass.h". I compile the files by calling:

```
g++ testclass.cpp main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testclass.hpp"

int main()
{
    testclass foo(56);

    std::cout << "Object in cpp\t" << numberobject.getNumber() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

testclass header

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H

class testclass
{
 private:
    int number;

 public:
    testclass();
    testclass(int);
    int getNumber();
};

#endif //TESTCLASS_H
```

testclass.cpp

```
#include "testclass.hpp"

testclass::testclass()
{
}

testclass::testclass(int number)
{
    this->number = number;
}


int testclass::getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
```

There will be a compile error

```
testclass.cpp:7:1: error: prototype for ‘testclass::testclass(int)’ does not match any in class ‘testclass’
 testclass::testclass(int number)
 ^
testclass.h:4:7: error: candidates are: testclass::testclass(const testclass&)
 class testclass
       ^
testclass.cpp:3:1: error:                 testclass::testclass()
 testclass::testclass()
 ^
```

However, if I change the "testclass.h" to "testclass.hpp" and also change all `#include` statment from `#include "testclass.h"` to `#include "testclass.hpp"`, it works well.

Why I can't compile the .h file? And is there anyway to compile with .h file?

Comment: You should post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sure that both headers has the same content? Have you checked `#ifndef XXX_H` guards are correct and different for all your includes? Try to look on pre-processed file and see that correct file was included.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that there is a strange 'testobject.h.gch" file under the same directory. It works fine after I remove it.